# Why is it not possible to assign an array several elements in place whereas it is if initialising an array when it is being defined?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

We can do this:

```
int list[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

But we cannot do this:

```
int list[5];
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

I presume `list` in the second case just decays to a pointer, but still it does not decay when being defined like `int list[5]`. I do not completely understand what is going on when an array is defined and when it is accessed after definition and what is the difference and why does this difference even exist. I didn't manage to find the answer, I'll delete the post if there is one.

Comment: Array name is not assignable. It is a non-modifiable l-value.

Comment: @haccks still it is if initialised straight away when defined

Comment: Originally C only allowed array initializers for static arrays.  Later, they added it for non-static arrays, which is a limited form of dynamic array assignment, but only in initializers.

Comment: @haccks what is `list[]` in `int list[] = { ... }` then? Don't we still assign several values to a name?

Comment: @TomKarzes I think this is not what I asked about

Comment: @Kaiyaha You're confusing declarations that include initializers, with assignment statements.  That's probably the source of your confusion.  Your first example is a declaration with an initializer.  Your second is a declaration without an initializer, followed by an assignment.  The assignment is not allowed.  The declaration with an initializer is.

Comment: @TomKarzes The question is about the difference between assigning a set of values to an array when defined and assigning afted definition

Comment: @Kaiyaha Yes, and I have answered that.  Initializers allow a very limited form of array assignment.  Assignment statements do not.

Comment: @TomKarzes so in the first case an array is initialised, and in the second one an array is assigned (kind of), right?

Comment: @Kaiyaha Correct.  The first case is allowed, but the second is not.  And traditionally even the first case was only allowed for static arrays, but that restriction was lifted in more recent versions of C.

Comment: @TomKarzes The array name in the second case decays to a pointer, that is clear, we cannot assign several values to a variable supposed to only hold one. In the first case however, the array name does not decay to a pointer, it is an array here. Right? Isn't it that an array name only represents an array when being defined (and used with `sizeof`) and all the rest time it represents a pointer?

Comment: @Kaiyaha No, the array name in the second case does *not* decay to a pointer.  An array name simply is not allowed on the left hand side of an assignment like that.  It's an error.  Array names decay to pointers only in certain contexts.  Appearing bare on the left side of an assignment is not one of them.  Try changing the assignment to something like `list = 0;`  The error message will say something like "assignment to expression with array type".  Not pointer type.  Array type.

Comment: @TomKarzes completely confusing now. I've always thought it does decay in these cases. Now I see it is not. So you mean a bare array name on its own never decays to a pointer? (like when appearing on the left-hand side of an assignment operator)

Comment: @Kaiyaha No, I mean an array name decays into a pointer in some contexts, such as being passed as an argument to a function, or having an integer value added to it, and does not decay in other contexts, such as being used as the argument in a `sizeof` expression.  In the case of assignment, *if* assignment to an array were allowed, then it would not decay, since doing so would discard needed information (e.g. size).  But assignment to an array is not allowed, so there's little point in speculating about it.  It would be more productive to try to understand the cases that *are* allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int list[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

is not an assignment. It is initialization.

```
int list[5];
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

is definition of an uninitialized array, followed by (an attempt at) assignment.

While you can initialize an array (except for variable-length arrays which cannot even be initialized!), you cannot assign to it.

The reason is in some quite historic decisions made in early 1970s. C was made more or less compatible with a language named B. In B there was no array type, instead what was an array name was a pointer in B; and you could assign to it, not to change the values inside the array, but to make it point elsewhere.

C arrays were different in that the C arrays *are* objects themselves having size and all. To aid in porting B programs to C, the "array name decays to a pointer to the first element" was introduced. The only problem was the array assignment which could not possibly follow B semantics - so this was made into an error altogether.

More information available from [Ritchie's C history page](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html).

While array assignment is unlikely to become reality, there are some workarounds you can use, for example:

```
memcpy(list, (const int[]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, sizeof list);
```